# obtaining kernel characteristics from Kernel Density Estimation (sklearn)

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, gaussian, kernel-density

In the [sklearn example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neighbors/plot_kde_1d.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-neighbors-plot-kde-1d-py), the synthesized data has been sampled from the weighted sampling of two gaussian distributions with mean and std of `[0,1]` and `[5, 1]` responsible for 30% and 70% of the samples respectively. Assume using the `gaussian` kernel with `bandwidth=1` we have obtained the following result (output of KDE estimator fitted to the train data):

[image]

Is it possible (mathematically and practically) to recover the characteristics of estimated kernels? for example in this case, we read the values `[0,1]` and `[5, 1]` from the fitted model? (assuming the fitting process has been done properly)

Answer (score 0):

### No, it is not possible.

The sklearn KernelDensity class only allows (1) to sample new data points and (2) to compute the log-likelihood under the model. In your example, you can read the mean and the standard deviation of your gaussian mixture model by eye, but it has nothing to do with the algorithm under the hood of Kernel Density Estimation.

A standard workflow of the sklearn KDE algorithm is as follow:

1. Instantiate the KDE instance with the chosen hyparameters (in particular, provide the kernel and the bandwidth).
2. The `fit()` method assigns the training dataset to the KDE instance. Documentation here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity.html#sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity.fit
3. The `sample()` method generates new data points by (i) first randomly choosing a data point `x` in your training dataset and (ii) draw a random instance from a Normal distribution centered at `x` with standard deviation `h` (where `h` is your KDE bandwidth).
4. Compute the log-likelihood of your generated sample under the model using `score()` and `score_sample()`

Therefore, there is no such thing as "the characteristics of the estimated kernels".